# SELECT rows by to many relationship ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty basic table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (id UUID PRIMARY KEY, room_type VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (room_id UUID, user_id UUID);
CREATE TABLE users (id UUID PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
```

Given a list of user ids, I need to find any room that has that exact list of users associated with it.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select s.room_id
from subscriptions s
group by s.room_id
having count(distinct case when s.user_id in ( . . . ) then s.user_id end) = N and
       count(*) = N;
```

Where N is the size of the list.  For instance:

```
having count(distinct case when s.user_id in (1, 2, 3) then s.user_id end) = 3 and
       count(distinct s.user_id) = 3;
```

Note:  use `count()` without `distinct` if you know that the user/room pairs are unique.